# Is there a tool that provides hotkeys for crop ratios when editing raw files?

Tags: software, cropping

I crop a huge portion of my photos to an aspect ratio that's different from the original source. I'm looking for a tool that let me do that quickly via hotkeys. For example, I'd like to be able to switch between the original aspect ratio and a 5x7 or 4x6 ratio with a single keyboard command and avoid having to make the change with the mouse (which is considerably slower). I do the cropping on my RAW files, so whatever the tool is, it'll need to work with those.

I don't see a way to do that natively with Lightroom. I've tried the Visual Source VSCO Keys plugin and that doesn't do it either. (I asked them about it and they said they would look into it for a future version). I'm fine with using another application besides Lightroom as long as Lightroom and Photoshop can read the XMP data and know where I'm cropping.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Looking for the same. Bonus if it can work in the Library module rather than Develop. The quick-develop tool is really missing the crop feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Lightroom on a Mac, I would look into Keyboard Maestro, a Quickeys-like macro program that will allow one to automate system and GUI actions like moving a cursor to a set location and selecting things like dropdown menus.

A demo can be downloaded from their website.

http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/